# Laravel Guzzle getting destination and due time from a page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, guzzle

I want my website to scrape information from this page beta.tfgm.com/public-transport/tram/stops/oldham-central-tra‌​m and in particular I want to scrape destination and due time from that website and give me an output.

At this moment my controller looks like this:

```
function guzzle(){
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$results = $client->get('https://beta.tfgm.com/public-transport/tram/stops/oldham-central-tram');
//$result->getBody();
//return view('hello')->with('results', $results);
//dd($result);
$results->getBody()->getContents();
dd($results);
return view('hello');
}
```

And the output is:

```
Response {#190 ▼
  -reasonPhrase: "OK"
  -statusCode: 200
  -headers: array:8 [▼
    "Content-Security-Policy" => array:1 [▶]
    "Content-Type" => array:1 [▶]
    "Date" => array:1 [▶]
    "ETag" => array:1 [▶]
    "X-Content-Security-Policy" => array:1 [▶]
    "X-WebKit-CSP" => array:1 [▶]
    "Content-Length" => array:1 [▶]
    "Connection" => array:1 [▶]
  ]
  -headerNames: array:8 [▼
    "content-security-policy" => "Content-Security-Policy"
    "content-type" => "Content-Type"
    "date" => "Date"
    "etag" => "ETag"
    "x-content-security-policy" => "X-Content-Security-Policy"
    "x-webkit-csp" => "X-WebKit-CSP"
    "content-length" => "Content-Length"
    "connection" => "Connection"
  ]
  -protocol: "1.1"
  -stream: Stream {#188 ▶}
}
```

However how can I access specific html class, scrape information from it and output it on my page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dd` is not useful for you here, try this :

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$results = $client->get('https://beta.tfgm.com/public-transport/tram/stops/oldham-central-tram');

print_r($results->getBody()->getContents()); // The HTML content
```

Comment: I get: GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream Object ( [stream:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => Resource id #238 [size:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => [seekable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1 [readable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1 [writable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1 [uri:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => php://temp [customMetadata:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => Array ( ) )

Comment: awesome how can you only keep specific data, so I want to keep the table only instead of whole page? Can you like set it only to scrape a table?

Comment: You will need to parse the whole HTML, you should take a look at this package : https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte

Comment: so this will allow me to actually only extract everything in a html tag and output that only?

Comment: Yes I think, never used it that way.