# Goutte Crawler convert JSON

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, guzzle, goutte

https://api.cinelist.co.uk/get/times/cinema/10565

This link gives me a json list of title and times that the cinema is playing that specific film. I want to get that information and convert it to string however how is that possible? I have used json_decode and it says that node list is empty.

Here's my code:

```
function odeon(){
    $client = new Client();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.cinelist.co.uk/get/times/cinema/10565');
    //print $crawler->text()."\n";
    json_decode($crawler);
    print_r($crawler);
}
```

Comment: `print_r(json_decode($crawler));`

Comment: it says that json_decode expects a string and instead get's an object

Comment: The DomCrawler object doesn't seem to have any method to dump the complete response data. If you were to use Guzzle, then you could do this `print_r(json_decode((string) $crawler->getBody()));`.

Comment: so how could I do the same function using guzzle? I have it installed however I couldn't figure it out

Comment: Like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44266346/5892849 from your other question. Just pass the result into json_decode. You should try reading some tutorials first to understand how scrapers work and read Guzzle's documentation. You seem to be trying to achieve too much without even knowing the basics, it's apparent from your previous questions. My suggestion would be to go through the Guzzle documentation. Then use symfony's `DomCrawler` Component to scrape the html. You can directly convert json responses to an array or object using json_decode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

file_get_contents() does the trick for simple things like these.

```
function odeon(){
    $data = file_get_contents('https://api.cinelist.co.uk/get/times/cinema/10565');

    $data = json_decode($data);
    return view()->make('odeon')->with(['listings' => $data->listings]);

}
```

and then in your blade simply do something like this:

```
@foreach($listings as $listing)
    <strong>{{$listing->title}} </strong>: 
    @foreach($listing->times as $time)
        <p>{{$time}}</p>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: looks all good however I need to return the data into blade template so I can style it into div etc

Comment: Well that is not what you asked for. I will update my example with some more context.

Comment: function odeon doesn't return a view so how can I tell it to use blade?

Comment: Your question was not about learning laravel. It was how to convert a json to string. I can update my example, but for better answers please ask what you need to know and not only a part of it.